# How to get previous sunday and saturday of current day in PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I need a way to get the date range of a previous Sunday to Saturday for the current date.

Example, if today is 8/15 I would want 8/4 - 8/10.

Comment: Today is 15 (Thursday). The last sunday was the 11th, not 4th.

Comment: What must happen if current date is Saturday? Example: if today was 8/10; should range still be 8/4 - 8/10 ?

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Current date is 8/10. Code if date range must be 8/4 - 8/10 :

```
$to = new DateTime('2013-08-10');
$to->modify('-' . (($w = $to->format('w')) != 6 ? $w + 1 : 0) . ' day');
$from = clone $to;
$from->modify('-6 day');

echo $from->format('m/d') . "-" . $to->format('m/d'); # 08/04-08/10
```

#### 2. Current date is 8/10. Code if date range must be 7/28-8/03 :

```
$to = new DateTime('2013-08-10');
$to->modify('last Saturday');
$from = clone $to;
$from->modify('-6 day');

echo $from->format('m/d') . "-" . $to->format('m/d'); # 07/28-08/03
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do something like this:-

```
$end = (new \DateTime())->modify('last saturday');
$start = (new \DateTime())->setTimestamp($end->getTimestamp())->modify('- 6 days');
$interval = new \DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end->add($interval));

foreach($period as $day)
{
    $result[] = $day->format('d-m-Y');
}
var_dump($result);
```

Output:-

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string '04-08-2013' (length=10)
  1 => string '05-08-2013' (length=10)
  2 => string '06-08-2013' (length=10)
  3 => string '07-08-2013' (length=10)
  4 => string '08-08-2013' (length=10)
  5 => string '09-08-2013' (length=10)
  6 => string '10-08-2013' (length=10)
```

The [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes are extremely useful.

Answer (score -4):

```
function getPreviousSundayAndSatruday($today = NULL)
{
    $today = is_null($today) ? time() : $today;

    // If today is Sunday, then find last week
    if(date("w", $today) == 0){
        $saturdayTimeStamp = strtotime("last Saturday");
        $sundayTimeStamp = strtotime("last Sunday");
    }
    // If it is Saturday, check from last Sunday until today
    else if(date("w", $today) == 6){
        $saturdayTimeStamp = strtotime("this Saturday");
        $sundayTimeStamp = strtotime("last Sunday");
    }
    // Else it's a day of the week, so last Saturday to two Sundays before.
    else{
        $saturdayTimeStamp = strtotime("last Saturday");
        $sundayTimeStamp = strtotime("last Sunday - 1 week");
    }

    return array(
        'saturday'  => $saturdayTimeStamp,
        'sunday'    => $sundayTimeStamp
    );
}
```